# Creating new user with home directory linux

Tags: linux, scripting

I am having some trouble with creating a new linux user using a script which should be basic, but its doing my head in as i am trying to figure out how it works

This is the code

```
clear
cd home
echo "Enter Username"
read username
echo "Enter Password"
read password
useradd -m $username
usermod -a -G myGroup $username
grep myGroup /etc/group
```

I fixed the issue with the username, but I don't know how to store the password to the username

I am in root when this script is executed

All input appreciated!

Comment: when you use sudo su username, are you in root by any chance?

Comment: yes, i was in root user.

Comment: it won't ever ask you for a password when you are in root, try logging in as another user and then try doing sudo su username and it should ask you for a password

Answer (score 0):

Try:
clear
cd home
echo "Enter Username"
read username
echo $username
useradd -m $username
usermod -a -G myGroup $username
passwd $username
grep myGroup /etc/group

Note: I don't think that adding users in this way is recommended practice and I am assuming that you are sudo'ing this script.
This should get you close to what you are after

Comment: i used the $username and it worked, but the password is still trouble

Comment: Password is not used in your script!

Comment: I suspect you want usermod -a -G myGroup -p $password $username

Comment: yea, but i still can't set a password for a new user

Comment: Are you still having trouble with the password?

Answer (score 0):

I more succinct answer if you don't like the one above:

clear
echo "Enter Username"
read username
adduser --gecos "" --ingroup myGroup $username